# A question about converging in probability of empirical time a random sequence attaining a value

Tags: probability

Let $X_, X_2, \cdots$ be independent random variables, and suppose that $p_i
:= P[X_i = 0]$ satisfies $0 < p_i < 1$ for every $i = 1, 2, \cdots$  For every $n > 1$ let $N_n := \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}_{\{X_i =0\} }$ denote the number of times the finite random sequence $X_1, \cdots , X_n$ enters zero. Prove that $\frac{N_n}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n p_i} \to 1$ in probability as $n \to \infty$.

---

Neither weak/strong law of large numbers can be used here. How to start off? Any hint is appreciated.
EDIT: I have figured out how to do this. A direct computation of variance and expectation followed by using Chebyshev's inequality should work. Since $E[N_n] \to \infty$.

Comment: What makes you think it is true for all $p_1,p_2,\ldots$ restricted solely by $0 < p_i < 1$?

Comment: @Henry they are just the probability of some events(so are related to characteristic functions.) So basically we are trying to show $\frac{N_n}{E[N_n]} \to 1$ in probability

Comment: Thank you, I have figured out how to do this. A direct computation using Chebshev's ineqaulity should work. Since $E[N_n] \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is correct if $\mathbb E[N_n]=\sum\limits_1^n p_i  \to \infty$, but that does not have to be the case if the only restriction is $0 < p_i < 1$.

As a counterexample, suppose $p_i=2^{-i}$ so $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \mathbb E[N_n]=\sum\limits_1^\infty p_i=1$, and the sum over all the terms (let's call it $N_\infty$) has mean $1$ and variance $\frac23$. Then I think the limiting distribution has

- $\mathbb P\left(N_\infty =0\right) \approx 0.2887880950866$
- $\mathbb P\left(N_\infty =1\right) \approx 0.4639944324509$
- $\mathbb P\left(N_\infty =2\right) \approx 0.2085238591147$
- $\mathbb P\left(N_\infty =3\right) \approx 0.0359126356138$
- $\mathbb P\left(N_\infty =4\right) \approx 0.0026865084458$
- $\mathbb P\left(N_\infty =5\right) \approx 0.0000929195340$
- etc.

With this as the limiting distribution of  $\frac{N_n}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n p_i}$, it is clearly not a single value.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but how to approach this problem? It seems that the problem should have assumed $E[N_n] \to \infty$.

Comment: I think you have to treat the $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n p_i$ bounded and unbounded as $n$ increases separately.  In the bounded case, you can show a counter-example.  In the unbounded case perhaps you can say the mean of $\frac{N_n}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n p_i}$ is $1$ and the variance is less than something like $\frac{1}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n p_i}$ and then apply your Chebyshev inequality argument